# Scrolling Dynamic DIV

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a DIV which has images and hyperlinks, which are added in C# by CODE

```
mStr.Append(" <div id='wn'>");
mStr.Append("<div id='lyr1'> <ul id='horiz'>");

if (dv.Count > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++) {

        mStr.Append("<li width='450' height='110' style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px;'>");
        mStr.Append("<a href='PlayGame.aspx?GameID=" + GameLib.Utilities.Encrypt(dv[i][1].ToString()) + "'>");
        mStr.Append("<img src='../" + dv[i][10].ToString() + "' width='156px' height='109px' style='padding-left:0px;'  />");
        mStr.Append("</a>");
        mStr.Append("</li>");
    }
    mStr.Append("</ul></div></div>");
    RelatedGames.InnerHtml.Remove(0, RelatedGames.InnerHtml.Length);
    RelatedGames.InnerHtml = mStr.ToString();
}
```

..but the problem is that I want to scroll the DIV so that i can go through all images. I tried many ways in JQuery but it has been stuck and static. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Or, is there any other way that the same functionality can be achieved?

Comment: Where's the Javascript/jQuery part of it?

Comment: how about `overflow:scroll;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following CSS:

```
#lyr1 {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[Overflow](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) is a CSS property that specifies how content that is larger than its parents should be displayed. The default value is `visible`, which means that everything will be displayed, even if it goes beyond the size of its parent (which it does, in your case). Setting it to `auto` will make everything that doesn't fit in the parent hidden, and will add scrollbars whenever necessary. **To make scrollbars always visible, do `overflow: scroll;`.**

**Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DanVicBez/kNk4y/**

Comment: hello sir, actually I need to have two button (LEFT,RIGHT) so that clicking will show the image one by one by sliding image...I wanted to achieve like one in this slide show http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html.

Comment: Swebert, I am not sure how to do that, but that requires a good knowledge of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a css property <kbd>[overflow:scroll](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/overflow)</kbd> to the target div

```
<div id='lyr1' style='overflow:scroll'>
```

Comment: hello sir, actually I need to have two button (LEFT,RIGHT) so that clicking will show the image one by one by sliding image...I wanted to achieve like one in this slide show http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html.